# Anisble oneliner module call

Tags: module, ansible

Quick question is it possible to call ansible module in oneline ?
I tried:

```
ansible localhost -m maven_artifact  -e 'group_id=groupid' -o
localhost | FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "group_id must be set"}
```

I'm not able to figureout how to pass the group id an dI do not want to setup a playbook.

Thanks for the help.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I just have to add -a instead of -e

````
ansible localhost -m maven_artifact  -a 'group_id=groupid' -o```
````

Answer (score 0):

Quote from official [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html#why-use-ad-hoc-commands)

```
$ ansible [pattern] -m [module] -a "[module options]"
```

`-e` is for passing variables, what you need in this case is `-a` to pass arguments for the module.